# Attach to Property's setter

Tags: c#

I haven't found similiar post so I'm asking this.
Let's say I defined somewhere an application wide available static Property (I mean it's not local) and in one class I would like to know when this property is being changed. Apart from aop (transparentproxy etc.) which I think doesn't suit me well here (and I can't add that to project anyway), what are the options here?

One solution I can think of, which is probably a very nasty one, is to use some event that would be executed in the setter and just attach it in the class(es) which needs that.
Something like:

```
   public static event EventHandler CurrentNumberChanged= delegate {};
   public static int CurrentNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return currentNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            currentNumber = value;

            CurrentNumberChanged(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

I know it's really unsafe to use such events ( [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289002/how-to-raise-custom-event-from-a-static-class/289358#289358) ). And since I would use it in asp.net makes it even more ugly. Do you have any advices  ?

Comment: The first thing to do is most likely to reconsider the design. If you still need to to it, you'll have to be very careful to always unsubscribe to the event, otherwise you are very likely to create a huge memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a variation on the Observer pattern to the same effect. Not sure what your threading requirements are, and I suspect this suffers from similar dereferencing problems as [How to raise custom event from a Static Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289002/how-to-raise-custom-event-from-a-static-class/289358#289358) (although would have to play with the code a bit more to bottom that out):

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class StaticObservable
    {
        private static int currentNumber;

```
    private static readonly List<IObserver> observers = new List<IObserver>();

    public static int CurrentNumber
    {
        get{return currentNumber;}
        set
        {
            currentNumber = value;
            foreach (var observer in observers)
            {
                observer.NotifyChange();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Attach(IObserver observer)
    {
        observers.Add(observer);
    }

    public static void Detach(IObserver observer)
    {
        observers.Remove(observer);
    }
}

public interface IObserver
{
    void NotifyChange();
}

public class ObserverImpl : IObserver
{
    public void NotifyChange()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Number has changed");
    }
}


public class AppWrapper
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadLine();

        var observerImpl1 = new ObserverImpl();
        var observerImpl2 = new ObserverImpl();

        StaticObservable.Attach(observerImpl1);
        StaticObservable.Attach(observerImpl2);

        StaticObservable.CurrentNumber = 1;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The answer you mentioned just said that if you forget to unsubscribe some instace from a static event then this instance will live forever.

Answer (score 0):

EventHandler is a bit too much I think, why not just create some boolean flag with a setter in the class that needs to receive the message, and whenever CurrentNumber's setter is triggered, call the setter of that boolean flag.
I'd like to be a little more descriptive here, but the data is not sufficient to suggest actual code.

Comment: Not relevant, as the class is not accessible from the property and of course the class is not static.