# Does adding trivial handler to event cause significant overhead?

Tags: c#

From the content of the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289002/how-to-raise-custom-event-from-a-static-class) I learned a new trick; to add a trivial handler to an event in order to avoid null checking when it is raised.

```
public static event EventHandler SomeEvent = delegate {};
```

and to invoke it without the null checking:

```
SomeEvent(null,EventArgs.Empty);
```

Does this add significant overhead? If not, why isn't something like this built in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this add significant overhead? If not, why isn't something like this built in?

It doesn't add *significant* overhead - merely a delegate call when the event is raised.

As for why it's not built-in - there are a couple of downsides:

1. This isn't necessarily bullet proof - you can still [clear the handler list afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-a-control), in which case, you'd still need the proper checking.
2. This does add overhead - while minor, that overhead could be problematic in specific scenarios.

Comment: One would think that if they were to build in that functionality that clearing the handler list would leave the trivial one behind. Could you provide an example of a scenario where the added overhead would be problematic?

Comment: @NominSim Sockets and timers come to mind - in those scenarios, you wouldn't want any extra overhead...

Comment: Well you'll have overhead either way, either checking against null or calling a trivial delegate, which is more?

Comment: @NominSim null check would be lower overhead than the delegate call - and still required (as the handler list could be cleared)

Comment: I just wrote a trivial program to check, the delegate call takes 1.45 times longer than the null check when performed in method, but when a method is called (as in most standards that I have seen) i.e. `OnSomeEvent(){ if (SomeEvent != null){ SomeEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);}}` the null checking takes 2.48 times longer than the delegate.

Comment: Oh I meant also to say that if it were a built in feature, I would expect that they would make a special case for when the handler is cleared to simply add another trivial delegate.

Comment: @NominSim That would require a CLR change, in which case, they could just do the null check, instead ;)

Comment: @NominSim As for your timings - thats' actually not the standard - you should make a temporary for the handler, and check against (and use) it - I suspect, with an empty case, the null check will still be faster, if profiled correctly.  In any case, it's still "correct" given the language and CLR.

Comment: That is how I wrote it, the program was faster with the null check when I didn't add an additional method call, but when I did it was slower. I'm sure I am probably doing something wrong though, thank you btw for humoring me with this.