# How do I update GUI text log in C#

Tags: c#

I have a tab in my GUI I would like to be an auto-updating dev log. It currently only updates the initial time. How do I update this.devLogRichTextBox.Text with every change in DevLog.DevLog.log?

```
// 
// devLogRichTextBox
// 
this.devLogRichTextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
this.devLogRichTextBox.Name = "devLogRichTextBox";
this.devLogRichTextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1195, 368);
this.devLogRichTextBox.TabIndex = 0;
this.devLogRichTextBox.Text = DevLog.DevLog.log; // This doesn't do what I want. This sets the text one time to string DevLog.DevLog.log
```

I would like to add lines to this log from anywhere in the program:

```
namespace DevLog
{
    public static class DevLog
    {
        public static string log = "Default";
        public static void addToLog(string addition)
        {
            log += addition + "\r\n";
        }

        public static void clearLog()
        {
            log = "";
        }

        public static void dumpLogToFile()
        {
            //Dump log to a file on HD
        }

        public void updateGUIDevLog()
        {
             //??
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried some things with pointers, but maybe the best option is to have it update at a fixed interval, or better yet, invoke some sort of update whenever a modification is made.

Comment: Essentially you need either an event or (if you're using WPF) you can do with a Binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an event on your DevLog class which you fire every time the log is updated.

Add this field to your DevLog class

`public static event EventHandler LogUpdated`

Now, at the end of your `addLog` function

```
if (LogUpdated != null)
    LogUpdated(null, EventArgs.Empty);
```

And now, in your GUI class:

```
DevLog.LogUpdated += (o, e) => 
{
    this.devLogRichTextBox.Text = DevLog.log;
};
```

Now, every time your log is updated it will fire the `LogUpdated` event

Comment: Very awesome sir! Taught me about the eventhandlers and works perfectly

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked for you. You might want to investigate MVVM though, like some of the other posters mentioned, it'll make your life a lot easier down the line.

Answer (score 0):

You could raise an event from the logger:

```
public static event EventHandler<string> LogLineAdded = delegate { };

public static void addToLog(string addition)
{
    string logLine = addition + "\r\n";
    log += logLine;
    LogLineAdded(null, logLine);
}
```

Then subscribe from the client form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DevLog.LogLineAdded += DevLog_LogLineAdded;
}

private void DevLog_LogLineAdded(object sender, string logLine)
{
    this.devLogRichTextBox.Text += logLine;
}

private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DevLog.LogLineAdded -= DevLog_LogLineAdded;
}
```

[Unsubscribing from a static event from an instance handler is important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289002/how-to-raise-custom-event-from-a-static-class).